# Как сделать массив с изменяемыми координатами Python?

Tags: python, массивы, координаты

Есть массив с координатами тела, когда я добавляю новый элемент тело должно двигаться таким образом, что второй элемент берет значения от первого, третий от второго и тд.
Например если в теле 5 элементов:

```
        array_row[-5] = array_row[-4]
        array_column[-5] = array_column[-4]
        array_row[-4] = array_row[-3]
        array_column[-4] = array_column[-3]
        array_row[-3] = array_row[-2]
        array_column[-3] = array_column[-2]
        array_row[-2] = array_row[-1]
        array_column[-2] = array_column[-1]
```

Как сделать так из этого общую формулу?
Я пытался сделать так, но он выдает ошибку:

```
for i in range (len(array_row)):
     array_row[k-1] = array_row[k]
     array_column[k-1] = array_column[k]
```

Comment: itertools.accumulate

Answer (score 1):

Используйте возможности `collections.deque`:

```
from collections import deque

my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
my_que = deque(my_list, maxlen=len(my_list))
print(list(my_que))
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
my_que.appendleft(0)
print(list(my_que))
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```